# Getting user's location not working after Swift 4 update

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, ios11, swift4

I've just updated to the Xcode 9 and Swift 4 and it has broken at lot of my functions. One of which being how I get the user's location, zoom in on it on launch, detecting annotation selection and various other tasks. They don't work at all. My view controller class code is below.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import Pulley
import CoreLocation

class ChildMapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    var isInitialized = false


    func startBackgroundLocationUpdates() {
        self.manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        manager.activityType = .fitness
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        if !isInitialized {
            isInitialized = true
            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
            let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

}

    struct loc {
        let title: String
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double
    }

    var locs = [
        loc(title: "New York, NY",    latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228),
        ]

    func placeAnnotations() {
        let annotations = locs.map { location -> MKAnnotation in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            annotation.title = location.title

            return annotation
        }
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }


    var position:PulleyPosition!

    func mapView(_ didSelectmapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        Shared.shared.annotation = view.annotation!



        if Shared.shared.annotation is MKUserLocation {
            Shared.shared.nameString = "My Location"
        } else {
            loadData()
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view:
        MKAnnotationView) {
        let drawerContent = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerViewController")
        if let drawer = self.parent?.parent as? PulleyViewController {
            drawer.setDrawerContentViewController(controller: drawerContent, animated: false)
            drawer.setDrawerPosition(position: PulleyPosition.partiallyRevealed, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func loadData() {
        let number = (Shared.shared.annotation?.title)!
        if let number = number {
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            ref.child("safehouses").child("\(number)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let name = snapDict?["name"] as? String
                let phone = snapDict?["phone"] as? String


                let current = CLLocation(latitude: (self.manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
                let destination = CLLocation(latitude: Shared.shared.annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: Shared.shared.annotation.coordinate.longitude)

                let distance2 = current.distance(from: destination)
                let distance1 = round(distance2)


                if distance1 >= 1000 {
                    if distance1 < 10000 {
                        let distance3 = distance1/1000
                        let distance = Double(round(10*distance3)/10)
                        Shared.shared.typeString = "Safehouse · " + String(distance) + " km"
                    } else {
                        let distance3 = distance1/1000
                        let distance = round(distance3)
                        Shared.shared.typeString = "Safehouse · " + String(distance) + " km"
                    }
                } else {
                    let distance = self.forTailingZero(temp: distance1)
                    Shared.shared.typeString = "Safehouse · " + distance + " m"
                }



                if let name = name {
                    if let phone = phone {
                        Shared.shared.nameString = name
                        Shared.shared.phoneString = phone
                        let drawerContent = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewDrawerViewController")
                        if let drawer = self.parent?.parent as? PulleyViewController {
                            drawer.setDrawerContentViewController(controller: drawerContent, animated: false)
                            drawer.setDrawerPosition(position: PulleyPosition.partiallyRevealed, animated: true)
                        }

                    }
                }
            })

        }
    }



    func forTailingZero(temp: Double) -> String{
        var tempVar = String(format: "%g", temp)
        return tempVar
    }

    func loop() {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("safehouses").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let ii = snapDict?["number"] as? Int
            let iii = Int(ii!)
            var i = 1
            while i <= iii{
                let name = String(i)
                ref.child("safehouses").child("\(i)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let longitude = snapDict?["longitude"]
                        as? String
                    let latitude = snapDict?["latitude"] as? String

                    if let longitude = longitude {
                        if let latitude = latitude {
                            let latitude1 = Double(latitude)
                            if let latitude1 = latitude1 {
                                let longitude1 = Double(longitude)
                                if let longitude1 = longitude1 {
                                    self.locs.append(loc(title: name, latitude: latitude1, longitude: longitude1))
                                    self.placeAnnotations()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                i = i + 1
            }

        })
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 175
        self.revealViewController().toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.easeOut

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }



        loop()
        mapView.delegate = self
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        Shared.shared.mapView = self.mapView
        startBackgroundLocationUpdates()
    }



}

final class Shared {
    static let shared = Shared()

    var nameString : String!
    var phoneString : String!
    var annotation : MKAnnotation!
    var mapView : MKMapView!
    var typeString : String!

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First add these property in info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>description1</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>description2</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>description3</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>accept to get location</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
```

And then after copy this view controller in your project

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

 var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        determineMyCurrentLocation()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        let value =   locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
         print("ankur :- \(region)")
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }

}
```

**Last step :- Open Capabilities -> In background modes -> click on location updates**

If any query comment it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these keys in info plist :

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Only when I select an annotation and run my function. It throws `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100795c6c)` on this line of code `               let current = CLLocation(latitude: (self.manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)`